# Remove a class from list item of live collection/ HTMLCollection

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a to-do list, but after shifting a list item from ongoing to completed tab, the tick-mark button created using js is also shifted to completed tab.

I have coded in such a way that every list item created in ongoing tab is binded to tick-mark(class).To remove that button, we need to remove the class i.e. binded to list item.

I have tried:

```
var nextlist = document.getElementById("completed").getElementsByTagName("li");
var j;
for(j = 0; j < nextlist.length; j++){
      nextlist[0].classList.remove("complete");
}
```

but it does not work.
And because this is in HTMLCollection, we cannot use querySelectorAll()

Answer (score 2):

You should replace `nextlist[0]` to `nextlist[j]`

```
var nextlist = document.getElementById("completed").getElementsByTagName("li");
var j;
for(j = 0; j < nextlist.length; j++){
      nextlist[j].classList.remove("complete");
}
```

Comment: I did, but still not working.

Comment: what exactly not working? any errors?

Comment: its just not processing the value j